# Rotate background image on click

Tags: jquery

What i am trying to do is get a image in css to rotate 90deg when clicked. I've checked multiple sites and posts and they all are close to what i want but don't seem to work right so i figured id just post my own question.

This is the image i need rotated url(../images./arrow.gif)

```
.collapsing {
background: #000 url(../images/arrow.gif) no-repeat 10px .7em;
font: bold 1.4em 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-serif;
padding: 7px 0 7px 35px;
color: #A0080D;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Basically i just want it to rotate down when clicked because i have a list that also drops down. And i also want to to rotate back when clicked again.

```
<div class="sidebox">
    <h1 class="collapsing">Current Projects</h1>
    <ul class="sidemenu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="top">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Paper">Technical Reporting Paper</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Calander">Build Calander for Site</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="">Develop App</a></li> -->
     </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this using Jquery? or does it have to be done some other way?

EDIT: I guess my main issue is how do i use jquery to access that image and make changes to it? I've tried changing where i declare the image (ex. in the html) but that just messes up the look of what i'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a jQuery plugin such as jqueryrotate https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/.

Comment: That would be great but I'm not sure how I would access the image in the first place in order to use the .rotate() on it.

Comment: If this is your image: ../images./arrow.gif, just import the plugin, then add it your menu using a <img> tag with any id you want (say "arrow" for example). 

Then, just call: 
`$("#arrow").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:180,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })
        }
     } 
   
});` Look at the example in the link I provided in my answer [link](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples)

Comment: I figured i might have to just throw it in a img tag, i was trying not to at first because i liked the way it looked at the moment and i just wanted to see if it was possible without a img tag. Took a little more css to make it look right but in the end everything worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rotating background image Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu-category-title').click(function(){
            var elem = $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')),
                arrow = $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow')

            if (!elem.is(':visible'))  {
                arrow.rotate({animateTo:90});
            } else {
                arrow.rotate({animateTo:90});
            }
            elem.fadeToggle('slow', function() {
            });

        return false;
    });
});
```

YOu html will looks like

```
<div class="menu-category-title" hook="01">TITLE 01
        <div class="menu-title-arrow" style="float: right;">↓</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-food-wrap" id="menu-01">
        test
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category-title" hook="02">TITLE 02
        <div class="menu-title-arrow" style="float: right;">↓</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-food-wrap" id="menu-02">
        test
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category-title" hook="03">TITLE 03
        <div class="menu-title-arrow" style="float: right;">↓</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-food-wrap" id="menu-03">
        test
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category-title" hook="04">TITLE 04
        <div class="menu-title-arrow" style="float: right;">↓</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-food-wrap" id="menu-04">
        test
    </div>
```

Css

```
.menu-category-title {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-food-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

I hope this will help you regards...:)